# Round data to the nearest even integer

Tags: r, dataframe

I think this should be easy to do. I have a data frame `df` with several columns. In column `a` I have different values between 1 and 100.

By comparing them I want to create a column `new` in the `df` to group them. The function to group them should round the value in `a` to **the nearest even integer** and save it in `df$new`. If `a = 0` it should set `new` to `NA`.

See the following example:

```
... a  ... new
---------------
    0      NA
   87.3    88
   88.1    88
   81.7    82
   79.2    80
   89.4    90
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest to use the internal `round` function combined with division/multiplication with 2.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0, 87.3, 88.1, 81.7, 79.2, 89.4))

# Round to nearest even integer
df$new <- 2 * round(df$a/2)

# Set 0 values of original array to NA in the result
df$new[df$a == 0] <- NA
```

This returns:

```
> df
     a new
1  0.0  NA
2 87.3  88
3 88.1  88
4 81.7  82
5 79.2  80
6 89.4  90
```

Comment: This doesn't work quite right if you are working with whole numbers (since R rounds to even, not up at 0.5).

Answer (score 5):

There are two options. Suppose you have toy data:

```
set.seed(0); x <- round(runif(10, 1, 5),1)  ## toy data
# [1] 4.6 2.1 2.5 3.3 4.6 1.8 4.6 4.8 3.6 3.5
```

You can do either of the two:

```
ceiling(x) - ceiling(x) %% 2
# [1] 4 2 2 4 4 2 4 4 4 4

floor(x) + floor(x) %% 2
# [1] 4 2 2 4 4 2 4 4 4 4
```

So for your data frame, you might do:

```
df$new <- floor(df$a) + floor(df$a) %% 2
df$new[df$a == 0] <- NA
```

where the final line setting `NA` part is easy to understand.

Comment: I understand, but **a** = 84.2 is getting **new** = 86, but should be 84. Same in your exaple, the first entry: 4.6 should get 4, not 6.
to clarify: everything between 1.5 ≤ x > 2.5 should become 2

Comment: @Zheyuan Li : It maybe `round` instead of `ceiling`.

Comment: @ Zheyuan Li : I am confused about desired output of `Max`. By basic rounding principle `4.6` must be rounded to `5` and according to `Max` desire it should be `6`.

Comment: @Max : Please specify your rounding principle for this particular situation. You stated `1.5 ≤x>2.5` should become `2`. What does this mean?